# Need to extract KBs off a text file using regular expressions in powershell or python

Tags: powershell

Example Input to evaluate.

1. I need to find extract the KB numbers out of the text below. using regular expressions in powershell or python.

"KB4565628 is not installed
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
"KB4565628 is not installed
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
"KB4565628 is not installed
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
"KB4565588 or KB4565635 is not installed
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
"KB4565588 or KB4565635 is not installed
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
"KB4565588 or KB4565635 is not installed
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
"KB4565588 or KB4565635 is not installed

Answer (score 3):

Use `Select-String`:

```
$strings = @(
"KB4565628 is not installed 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
"KB4565628 is not installed 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
"KB4565628 is not installed 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
"KB4565588 or KB4565635 is not installed 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
"KB4565588 or KB4565635 is not installed 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
"KB4565588 or KB4565635 is not installed 
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll Version is 4.8.3761.0#"
)

$KBIDs = $strings |Select-String 'KB\d{5,}' -AllMatches |ForEach-Object Matches |ForEach-Object Value
```

The regular expression pattern `KB\d{5,}` describes a string consisting of the literal characters `K` and `B`, followed by 5 or more digits.

As a result, `$KBIDs` will now contain the `KBXXXXXX` identifiers from the input strings.

To remove duplicates, use `Sort-Object -Unique`:

```
$UniqueKBIDs = $KBIDs |Sort-Object -Unique
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex to match all of the KBs followed by numbers (tested on your provided text string: `KB\d*`

Example:

```
import re


res = re.findall( r'KB\d*', '0#" "KB4565588 or KB4565635 is not installed...')

print(res)

>>> ['KB4565588', 'KB4565635']
```

So, if you would like to get only numbers without "KB", then you could do this:

```
filtered_res = [elem[2:] for elem in res]

print(filtered_res)

>>> ['4565588', '4565635']
```

Comment: The OP appears to be seeking a `powershell` solution and not a `python` solution.

Comment: @lit "...using regular expressions in powershell or python." - I think Python solution should be also okay for OP.